# Uploading file - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a contact form in my ASP.NET Core project, and it works. But now, I want to upload a file. Here is my code:

Model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class MailModels
    {
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        //[StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public IFormFile FileUploading { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View (part of view):

```
<label class="file_uploading">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileUploading, new { type = "file", @class = "input-file" })
</label>
```

Controller (part of controller):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index2(MailModels e, IFormFile file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(e.Email.ToString());
        message.Append("Name: " + e.Name + "\n");
        message.Append("Surname: " + e.SurName + "\n");
        message.Append("Email: " + e.Email + "\n");
        message.Append("Telephone: " + e.Telephone + "\n\n\n");
        message.Append("Text: " + e.Message + "\n");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        // .....
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ...so whats question here?

Comment: My question is how to send upload file with other information like name, surname,email,telephone,text.. I didn t know how to import file content and how to send it..

Comment: Remove the pointless `IFormFile file` parameter form your POST method, which will always be `null` (your file input is bound to the `FileUploading` property of your model)

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `MailModels e` from the parameters, and [check this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for a complete reference

Edit1:
Your code should look like this:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

// full path to file in temp location
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}

// process uploaded files
// Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

and your form should be something like:

`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="Index">`